# simplification of sequential scope functions

Tags: android, kotlin

I used a lot of following code in the application. Can I simplify this using something like extension method?

#### Fragment

```
lifecycleScope.launch {
    viewLifecycleOwner.repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED) {
        viewModel.StateOfSomething.collectLatest {
            withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What can I do to write something like below?

```
myScopeLaunch {
    viewModel.StateOfSomething.collectLatest {
        withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
        }
    }
}
```

It would be better if I could write it like below, but it should work in ***Main thread***.

```
myScopeLaunch {
   viewModel.StateOfSomething.collectLatest {

   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `lifecycleScope`, `viewModelScope`, or your own scope whose Context uses `Dispatchers.Main`, then there's no need to put that `withContext(Dispatchers.Main)` block in there anyway. `collect` is called using whichever dispatcher the coroutine is running in.

I'm not sure why you've defined an extra CoroutineScope instead of using `lifecycleScope` or `viewModelScope`, but you can define it to use `Dispatchers.Main.immediate`, just like those do:

```
private val myScope = SupervisorScope() + Dispatchers.Main.immediate + CoroutineName("myScope")
```

If you do want to specify a context other than the one used by the scope by default, it's a little cleaner to use `flowOn` instead of `withContext`. Less nesting of code.

```
myScope.launch {
    viewModel.StateOfSomething
        .flowOn(Dispatchers.Main)
        .collectLatest {

        }
    }
```

If you really want to shorten your repeated code, you could write an alternative to `launchIn` that also repeats on lifecycle, so you don't even have to launch your code in a nested coroutine.

```
fun <T> Flow<T>.collectLatestUiLaunchedUsing(
    lifecycleOwner: LifecycleOwner, 
    minActiveState: Lifecycle.State = Lifecycle.State.STARTED, 
    action: suspend (T) -> Unit
) {
    mapLatest { action(it) }
    .flowOn(Dispatchers.Main.immediate)
    .flowWithLifecycle(lifecycleOwner.lifecycle, minActiveState)
    .launchIn(lifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope)
}
```

Usage in a fragment:

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    //...

    viewModel.stateOfSomething.collectLatestUiLaunchedUsing(viewLifecycleOwner) { item ->
        //...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create an extension function for the `LifecycleOwner` class like this:

```kotlin
inline fun <T> LifecycleOwner.collectWithLifecycle(
    flow: Flow<T>,
    crossinline action: (T) -> Unit,
) {
    lifecycleScope.launch {
        repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED) {
            flow.collect {
                it?.let { action(it) }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then use it in your fragments like this:

```kotlin
collectWithLifecycle(someFlow) { value ->
   // TODO: Do something with the value
}
```